# How to Split a number and then raise each number to decending power

Tags: python-3.x

I want to know how to setup a loop to do the following

I have an integer of 8 digits which i want to split and then raise each digit to a power, (the power needs to start with 8  then start descending) then add everything to get a total AND THEN check with modulo 11 
for ex

```
int:30048117
sum=(3*8)+(0*7)+(0*6)+(4*5)+(8*4)+(1*3)+(1*2)+(7*1)
result=sum%11
```

If I'm  correct the answer is suppose to be 0

Python 3

```
number = input("enter number :")

for i in range(len(number)):
      for b in range(8,0,-1):
           sum += number[i]**b
           result = sum*(11/100)
 return result
```

I'm stuck this is only part of the code but I'm not sure how to split and raise to the power descending

Comment: There are several errors in this code as is before you try to add in the split portion of it. First: Sum isn't defined before you try to add to it. Second. the number is input as a string, which lets you loop on len(number) but then at sum you try to add a string and an int. You need to int number first

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm New to this and still learning i appreciate the help and the advice.

Comment: Use numpy much quicker

Comment: It's not clear if you wants to multiply the sum by 11% (as stated) or calculate check digit by calculating modulo 11 (more likely)...

Comment: @buran you are correct i need to check modulo 11 i did not know that i thought i have to multiply . how would i check it then?

Comment: @AntonBuitendag, n*11/100 is calculating  11% of n. n%11 is calculating modulo 11, i.e. the remainder of n/11. e.g. 100*11/100 = 11.0, 100%11 = 1

Comment: Also when calculating check digit it's usualy multiply by position index, not raise to power

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the outer for loop, you can iterate on the number string as you calculate your sum

```
number = input("enter number :")

num_sum = 0

#Iterate over number string and calculate sum
for b in range(8,0,-1):
    num_sum += int(number[len(number)-7])**b

#Take modulus 11
result = num_sum%11

print(result)
```

The result will be `0`

Answer (score 0):

```
num = input('enter number:')

# using slicing and enumearte()
print(sum(int(n) ** i for i, n in enumerate(num[::-1], 1)) % 11)

#using zip() and range()
print(sum(int(n) ** i for n, i in zip(num, range(8, 0, -1))) % 11)
```

Note: when calculating check digit you would multiply the number by position index, not raise to power. You need to check this requirement. In this case use * instead of **